# JavaScript is broken after clicking on a comment of a deleted answer in the inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

In my inbox, there is a reply to a comment on an answer which is deleted (The answer is deleted). Thus all comments are deleted.

This is the comment link: https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/530576?noredirect=1

When I follow the link, all JavaScript related to the top bar is broken. i.e. All drop-downs that are supposed to open, stop showing (StackExchange sites, Recent inbox messages, Recent achievements & help).

- The problem is reproducible if you click on the link above.
- If you have your browser console open, you can a JavaScript error.
- If you are a high rep user (I think it's 10k+?), or mod, you probably
  won't get the error if you can already see deleted answers (not sure
  how this work). But to reproduce it, you can log out (or just go into
  private browsing). The error is reproducible with a guest account.
- Error is reproducible in Chrome, Chromium & Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to have been fixed. All JavaScript functionalities seems to be working after clicking on the above link.